# Problem adding dependencies to Xcode Tests using Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, realm, swift-package-manager

I'm experimenting with SPM and, so far, adding dependencies to my main app target seems to work pretty well. However, the same isn't true when I try to add the same dependencies to a test target. Even though exactly the same libraries are listed in the 'Link Binary with Libraries' section, the dependencies are not recognised and/or seem to be missing their own (internal) dependencies.

I'm aware SPM is still something that many major frameworks only support on an experimental basis and this may be something that's not yet mature enough for production code but as I can't find anything to point me in the right direction, I thought I'd see if anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong (if anything) before I head back to Carthage.

Screenshots illustrating the difference between SPMs dependencies being recognised on the app target vs test target below. In the first image you can see that the compiler has access to all the Realm modules in the app target....

[image]

...but in the test target, most things (including some key dependencies required by RealmSwift) are missing despite adding the same package url.

[image]